# Why this program is not throwing any error?

Tags: c++, pointers

I went to an interview. Interviewer gave this question.
After seeing this question, I told him that there will be an error as `p` is undeclared. But when I ran the program in my PC, I was amazed with the answer/output as `ink` that too without any error. Please help me understanding this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
    char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;//Here
    p = ptr;
    ++p;
    cout << **p+1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're being tricked perhaps, by the order of the pointers to the words that are stored in `**ptr[]` - it's a 4 element array whose elements point to 'violet', 'pink', 'white', 'black'. `p=ptr` sets p to point to 'violet' (ptr[0]). `++p` then makes p point to 'pink' (ptr[1]). Finally, `**p+1` makes p point to the next char - the `i` in the word `pink`. Hence the result, `ink`

Comment: By the way, the `static char* s[] = ...` line should trigger a `conversion from string constant to char*` warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this :-

```
static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
                     ^        ^        ^       ^
                     |        |        |       |
                     |        |        |       |
                     |        |        |       |
                     +------------+    |       |
                          +---|---|----+       |
                          |   |   |            |
                     + ---|---|---|------------+
                     |    |   |   |
    char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1,s};
                     ^    ^
    char ***p;       |    |
                     |    |
    p=ptr ;  --------+    |
                          |
    ++p; -----------------+  {'p','i','n','k'}
                                   ^
    **p+1 -------------------------+
```

Comment: Considering you know last `***p` is same as separately `char ***p;`

Comment: Spectacular use of ascii art. And a fantastically well explained answer. Just noticed I was imprecise with regards to. `**p+1`. Haven't seen anything so neat since reading graphics tutorials on texture-mapping in the 90s. Them, and huffman or linked-list diagrams. :thumbs-up:

Comment: @P0W This is an excellent explanation, +5 if I can :) (consider 4 pending).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thanks, I realized OP just wanted a kind of representation

Comment: @P0W Yes its best and easiest way to explain, you can also use asciiflow sometime to draw ascii-drawings

Answer (score 6):

Since you are only asking about the declaration of `p`:

```
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;//Here
```

is the same as:

```
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s};
char ***p;
```